# Titanium Android - Custom Module. Supported source version 'RELEASE_6' less than -source '1.7' .

Tags: android, migration, titanium, appcelerator

I'm using com.artfulbits.aiCharts jar in one of my Custom Module and its working fine with Ti SDK 5.4.0.GA. but when i try to migrate it to new SDK im getting below error - JAVA VERSION related error

```
warning: Supported source version 'RELEASE_6' from annotation processor 'org.appcelerator.kroll.annotations.generator.KrollJSONGenerator' less than -source '1.7'
[ERROR] :  Note: [KrollBindingGen] Running Kroll binding generator.
[ERROR] :  Note: [KrollBindingGen] No binding data found, creating new data file: org.appcelerator.titanium.bindings/chart.json
[ERROR] :  Note: [KrollBindingGen] Found binding for module Chart
[ERROR] :  Note: [KrollBindingGen] Found binding for proxy Chart
[ERROR] :  Note: [KrollBindingGen] Found binding for proxy Line
[ERROR] :  /Users/i706495/Documents/Mobile/AppcWorkspace/chartnew/android/src/ingrs/chart/Crosshair.java:7: error: package com.artfulbits.aiCharts.Base does not exist
[ERROR] :  import com.artfulbits.aiCharts.Base.ChartArea;
```

Comment: Please add the first part of `appc info` where it shows all relevant versions

Comment: `Operating System

  Name                        = Mac OS X

  Version                     = 10.12.6

  Architecture                = 64bit

  # CPUs                      = 4

  Memory                      = 8.0GB

Node.js

  Node.js Version             = 4.6.1

  npm Version                 = 2.15.9


Appcelerator CLI

  Installer                   = 4.2.9

  Core Package                = 6.2.4


Titanium CLI

  CLI Version                 = 5.0.14
  node-appc Version           = 0.2.41`


I have all Ti SDKs version from 5.4.0.GA to latest version

Comment: What java version do you use?

Answer (score 0):

To use the latest SDK you need to update your toolchain:

```
Node.js   
Node.js Version    = 8.9.1   
npm Version        = 5.5.1

Appcelerator CLI   
Installer          = 4.2.12
Core Package .     = 7.0.2

Titanium CLI   
CLI Version .      = 5.0.14
node-appc Version  = 0.2.41
```

And check your JAVA version (1.8.0_65) and if you need to compile your module use NDK 12.1.2977051